# Event IDs 8311, 6803, 6110, and 6801 after new SSL certs installed and December CU

Tags: user-profile, ssl

About a week ago I installed new SSL certificates. Few days I configured the export thumbnailPhoto attribute for the User Profile Sync. I've never actually been able to successfully export the photos into AD. I see the following error in both the Event Viewer and the ULS logs:

**8311**

An operation failed because the following certificate has validation errors:\n\nSubject Name: CN=[REDACTED], OU=Domain Control Validated - QuickSSL(R) Premium, OU=See www.geotrust.com/resources/cps (c)11, OU=2945119243, O=[REDACTED], C=US, SERIALNUMBER=[REDACTED]\nIssuer Name: CN=GeoTrust DV SSL CA, OU=Domain Validated SSL, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US\nThumbprint:[REDACTED] \n\nErrors:\n\n SSL policy errors have been encountered. Error code '0x2'..

Not much help there. Contacted MS support and was told to install the latest CU (December 2011). Tested the CU earlier this week and decied to install during my change window yeseterday. Completed with no trouble and checkout went fine. I then try to kick off a Full Sync and now I'm seeing the 3 following Events in the logs:

**6803**

The management agent "MOSS-[GUID]" failed on run profile "MOSS_FULLIMPORT_[GUID]" because the server encountered errors.

**6110**

The management agent "MOSS-[GUID]" step execution completed on run profile "MOSS_FULLIMPORT_[GUID]" but the watermark was not saved.

Additional Information

Discovery Errors : "0"

Synchronization Errors : "0"

Metaverse Retry Errors : "0"

Export Errors : "0"

Warnings : "0"

User Action

View the management agent run history for details.

**6801**

The extensible extension returned an unsupported error.

The stack trace is:

"System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)

at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)

at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)

at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)

at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)

at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)

at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ManagementAgent.ProfileImportExportExtension.DownloadPictures(ProfileChangeData[] profiles)

at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ManagementAgent.ProfileImportExportExtension.Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.IMAExtensibleFileImport.GenerateImportFile(String fileName, String connectTo, String user, String password, ConfigParameterCollection configParameters, Boolean fFullImport, TypeDescriptionCollection types, String& customData)

Forefront Identity Manager 4.0.2450.34"

Any insight? I'll still continue to work with the MS Case Engineer but wondered if anyone has seen something similar. I'll post the outcome when/if we ever get there. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue. Had to use a wildcard cert. I have multiple web apps binded to port 443. I stop the web apps sites on the server that are not needed. Looks like SharePoint doesn't care that the site is stopped or started. Still need to have a correct cert in order for the sync to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Old post but also see article about using manage trusts in sp central admin to add the certificates.
This site explained it the best:
http://tristanwatkins.com/user-profile-picture-certificate-trusts/